# Index only plain text from HTML in solr

Tags: solr, solr5, solr6

I need to index only plain text from HTML and reject all other HTML tags.

For Example: I have html like

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>
       title
    </title>
    <link href="./test.html" rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1 style="height: 22px">
       header
      </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to index only 'header' text under the body tag and reject all other HTML tags in `_text_` field of solr.

I tried `<charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>` like below:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

But it still indexing the HTML tags attributes

According to solr documentation it should not index the HTML tags [solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/charfilterfactories.html#CharFilterFactories-solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory)

When i search `solr/testcore/select?q=_text_:height&wt=json` it giving me a record which should not be.

I tried in both `solr-5.3.1` and `solr-6.6.0`.

I stuck with this, please help me out.

Comment: So how are you indexing this file? And have you confirmed the type of the `_text_` field?

Comment: i am using command /var/www/html/solr-6.0.0/bin/post -p 9000 -c testcore -filetypes htm,html /var/www/html/test/testcore/test.htm and <field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're posting the HTML raw to Solr, it's being handled by [the extracting request handler ("Solr Cell")](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html) - which uses Apache Tika to extract content from the HTML file.

That means that the `_text_` field never sees the HTML tags at all, since the content has *already* been extracted by Apache Tika and the HTML tags have disappeared - so there's nothing to remove.

If you use a Solr client in a programming language of choice and submit the HTML as a field value directly, the the HTML stripping will take place as you expect (since the tags are then actually part of the content submitted to the field types internally in Solr).

I tried finding some way of [configuring the HTML Parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html#UploadingDatawithSolrCellusingApacheTika-Parserspecificproperties) in the bundled Tika version - it uses [the Tagsoup library](http://vrici.lojban.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) to do parsing, but I can't see any exposed configuration that would change what you're experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. One observation, when i check the same in 'Analysis' of solr panel against the '_text_' field for same input, it is giving me correct output after filter out all the HTML tags. so, is it something which i am missing.

Comment: You're missing what I wrote. When you submit the document the way you're submitting it, the text extraction happens in _Tika_. When it arrives in your analysis chain, the content has already been extracted from the HTML, and there are no HTML tags present. The analysis chain has nothing to remove. To counter this you can submit the HTML content as a regular field in a Solr update, instead of submitting the file to the extracting request handler.